# Does ActiveRecord update itself after ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Does ActiveRecord model update itself after `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('UPDATE ...')` was fired or it needs to be reloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, every time you do something with the connection directly, you are on your own and need to make sure everything is in sync.

```
c = Car.create! name: "Car 1"
c.name # => "Car 1"

Car.connection.execute "UPDATE cars SET name = 'Car 2' WHERE id = 1"

c.name # => "Car 1"
c.reload.name # => "Car 2"
```